# file_get_contents() is not working properly with youtube

Tags: ssl, php

I want to fetch data from youtube and I am using `file_get_contents()` method.

sometime it works fine but sometime it do not works and shows the following error

```
file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: SSL: crypto enabling timeout
file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Failed to enable crypto
file_get_contents(https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default?access_token=token&v=2&alt=json) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: operation failed
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

What does the above errors mean?

What is `SSL: crypto enabling timeout`

Comment: Can you open the url in browser?

Comment: Yes. It is showing properly in browser

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman this appears to be a bug in OpenSSL that was reported back in April see https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1085123#p1084175 and http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-server-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg73619.html if that is the case for you using SSL in file_get_contents(), fopen(), and cURL will be affected. What version of OpenSSL are you running? Should affect Windows servers as well since it OpenSSL binary causing the problem not the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't sometimes, because of SSL. Use cURL

This should suffice:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://youtube.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:20.0) Gecko/20121230 Firefox/20.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is an incompatibility between the server you are connecting to and the SSL library you have on your system.

Please check that the OpenSSL library you're using is not outdated. To verify this you probably need to contact your system administrator.

If the curl library uses the same SSL library, the suggested workaround by David Harris does not work as well.

Alternatively you can try to explicitly TLS1, this sometimes works. I suggest to test on the commandline first, e.g. by using the commandline version of `curl`.

Also you might want to take a look into [the SSL context options in PHP<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/context.ssl) which are used by the the `https://` wrapper (next to the [HTTP ones<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/context.http)).

Answer (score -2):

This error means that the time for execution of php page has came to an end. By default php module sets 30 seconds for the execution of any php page. You can increase it using

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', time in seconds as per your need);
```

Please write this function at the starting of the php page and set the time as per your need. It will overwrite the default execution time set by php for that particular page.

Comment: Not directly related to OPs error, only the one he is not having trouble with.